# Adicionar um action button no change_list do django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

Sou novo no Django, gostaria de saber como faço para adicionar um botão ao lado dos arquivos que foram adicionados e me leve a outra página, tal como a ação de deletar do combobox **Action**. Como posso fazer? Se puderem, apresentem um exemplo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]